# Responsive CSS Help - Image / Div Ratios

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I need some help with CSS / Responsive Code.  As my window size decreases I need all elements to decrease at the same ratio.  Having issues with that.  The arrow and the Rooster do no decrease as view port decreases.

The Rooster's shadow of his foot should stay slightly covered by the arrow.  The top of the arrow's body (not the point) should stay inline with the divide line between the grey and white sections.

I need some help with CSS / Responsive Code.  As my window size decreases I need all elements to decrease at the same ratio.  Having issues with that.  The arrow and the Rooster do no decrease as view port descreses.

The Rooster's shadow of his foot should stay slightly covered by the arrow.  The top of the arrow's body (not the point) should stay inline with the divide line between the grey and white sections.

http://www.bootply.com/fiF4GI3g0n

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.special_box {
  background-image: url("http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 434px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
.special_content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 85%;
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
}
.rodney {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  top: 4%;
  right: 16%;
  z-index: 5;
}
.rodney img {
  max-width: 315px;
  height: auto;
}
.special_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.special_arrow img {
  max-width: 916px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="special_box">
  <div class="special_content"></div>
  <div class="rodney">
    <img src="http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_rodney.png" alt="rodney" />
  </div>
  <div class="special_arrow">
    <img src="http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_arrow.png" alt="arrow" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Responsive Design

Try this. With this code the arrow decreases size according to screen size. You can edit it as you like,

> Use @media screen property to display content with respect to screen size

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
     margin: 0px;
}
.special_box {
     background-image: url("http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_bg.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% auto;
     height: 434px;
     max-width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1
}
.special_content {
     position: absolute;
     margin: auto;
     height: 85%;
     width: 70%;
     top: 0;
}
.rodney {
     position: absolute;
     margin: auto;
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: right;
     top: 4%;
     right: 16%;
     z-index: 5;
}
.rodney img {
     max-width: 315px;
     height: auto;
}
.special_arrow {
     position: absolute;
     margin: auto;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
}
.special_arrow img {
     width:60%;
     height: auto;
     display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1800px){
     .special_arrow img {
     width:98%;
     height: auto;
     display: block;
     }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="special_box">
  <div class="special_content"> </div>
  <div class="rodney"> <img    src="http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_rodney.png" alt="rodney"/> </div>
  <div class="special_arrow"> <img src="http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_arrow.png" alt="arrow"/> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is doing what I was already running into.  The arrow and the rooster do not start to resize until the screen width gets to them.  I need all elements to shrink / grow as one unit, without being a single graphic.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do this making the Rooster and arrow images with filler transparent space from the top.  Not sure this this the best way, but it works.

http://www.bootply.com/wfxTqAKJfo

CSS Code

```
body {
     margin: 0px;
}
.special_box {
     background-image: url("http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_bg.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% auto;
     height: 440px;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1
}
.special_content {
     margin: auto;
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     position: relative;
}
.rodney {
     background-image: url("http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_rodney.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 22% auto;
     background-position: right 21% top;
     height: 440px;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 5
}

.special_arrow {
     background-image: url("http://beta.madrooster.com/images/special_arrow.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 64% auto;
     background-position: left top;
     height: 440px;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="special_box">
  <div class="special_content">
  </div>
  <div class="rodney">
  <div class="special_arrow"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```